# Can i use shouldComponentUpdate in a component with a key prop in its ancestors?

Tags: reactjs

One of my components has a `key` prop to trigger a render when some condition is met :

```
<MyComponent key={ key }>
  <NestedComponent />
</MyComponent>
```

The `NestedComponent` implements `shouldComponentUpdate`. I observe that when `MyComponent` is re-rendered *because of* the `key` prop update, the `shouldComponentUpdate` method of `NestedComponent` is not called.

Am i correct in thinking that because of the `key` prop update, React skips the reconciliation process for the whole subtree, therefore mounting `NestedComponent` from scratch ? If not what am i missing ?

Maybe a bit more about my use case in case it helps.

I want to implement an infinite `ViewPager` on react-native : infinite in the sense that any given page has a successor and a predecessor, not in the sense circular. I can't of course render all pages at once, and i don't want to keep all the previously rendered pages around because they can be pretty expensive.

My current approach is a component that can be instantiated like so:

```
<InfiniteViewPager
  checksum={ myChecksum }
  bufferSize={ 2 }
  renderPageAtIndex={ myRenderPageFunction }
  onPageSelected={ onPageSelectedCallback }
/>
```

The `InfiniteViewPager` component is basically implemented like so:

```
<ViewPagerAndroid
  key={ this.props.checksum }
  initialPage={ this.props.bufferSize }
  onPageSelected={ this.props.onPageSelected } 
>
    { range(bufferSize * -1, bufferSize).map( i => this.props.renderPageAtIndex(i) ) }
</ViewPagerAndroid>
```

When the user navigates, I need to make the next item the current one, so that the infinite sequence can be navigated (that's the job of the `onPageSelected` callback). Thus the `key` prop : if i don't set it, the pages do not get re-rendered on nav.

The component works fine, but I would like to avoir re-rendering a component every page holds as it is quite expensive. Any ideas ?

Many thanks for your help!!

Comment: If you're not using `key` as an iterator, try using `id` or something similar. I've had issues with using the `key` prop name before when not explicitly iterating; wasn't able to find documentation that its a React keyword (although didn't look too furiously), but it seems to behave like it. Here's a pen noting I couldn't repro, but if you replace `i` with `key` it does break: http://codepen.io/mikechabot/pen/KzaMje?editors=1011

Comment: @lux thanks for your comment! Yes your right. Your codepen shows well updating a key prop causes the component to be mounted again and not updated. Besides accessing the key prop from the component is now forbidden. I guess I should rephrase my question for my specific use-case as using the key prop on `ViewPagerAndroid` is a hack needed when you update its children

Comment: @lux : after checking, the component is not mounted again when you update the key, but if I understand well the docs, the reconciliation lifecycle hooks are skipped : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html#keys

Answer (score 0):

use an ID for the key. the `key` should be unique for each component. you never use a number from an iterator (like `forEach()`) as a `key` unless you absolutely know that the list is never going to change (like a static table).

Comment: thanks for your answer! I am using ID based keys in the pages iterator and not their index in the array. The key on the top-level component is a needed hack with `ViewPagerAndroid` when its children are updated.